# Read array inside json in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pring value in array in json
(dload is a package to read json from url, and i want to access "username": "Mic123")

The json

```
{"id": "884087991803124224", "name": "Test's server", "instant_invite": null, "channels": [{"id": "884087923803124228", "name": "General", "position": 0}], "members": [{"id": "0", "username": "Mic123", "discriminator": "0000", "avatar": null, "status": "online", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/widget-avatars/-WkB9BvIc5Cf98sDorItQJAxQe2zFRSPu2rUMZa329E/ax2jbnjNHRatHiSN0ErxEAFWlGKIAriBh4nOAWpetSDxpYAZRM7a4vGODKipMekSOnHqEdvti4MFVMsYXPnK7gmYU6yowd8FhxSqq5dKIH2a3ouw7eW9uisKiCogMiBpbwOfM4K_GuZX5Q"}], "presence_count": 1}
```

I try this code

```
print(dload.json(licencekeyurl['members'][0]["username"]))
```

output
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: please, provide [mre] and explain exactly what you want to access.  what is `dload`, what is `licencekeyurl`?

Comment: And what happens? What is dload.json?

Comment: Please provide a proper MRE along with the expected results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key,value in data.items():
if key == "members":
    for key1,value1 in value[0].items():
        print(value1)
```